# Getting always -1 from Sequence called from stored procedure on EF 6

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I have a Sequence called from EF in my project throught this stored procedure

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetSecF1] 
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.PedidosFaisan
END
```

when I call

```
var consec = dataContext.GetSecF1();
```

I all ways get -1 as value, if I excecute the stored procedure directly from the database I get this: **(I changed the sequence name to match with this example)**
[image: Stored procedure from SMS]

The value is increased successful don't understand why is the zero there, and why EF returns -1

Any one have a clue why this happened?

Comment: please provide more information mostly around you application layer, how do you call the sproc , your repository

Comment: The 0 is there because you are comparing a string to a number and they are not equal. Change the `=` to a `+ convert(varchar, @return_value)`

Answer (score 1):

`GetSecF1` needs to RETURN the next value, not select it.

You'll need to select into a variable and return the variable.